# Rename an a new downloaded file to a number assigned to it

Tags: python

Hi I'm still new in Python and I wanted to ask how to fix this code. Basically what i wanted to do is everytime i run this code this code downloads it from a certain api (for this ex i give this a Covid API) and then everytime I run the code it would save it with a new number assigned to it. For example if the former file is name 0.JSON the next time I run the code it should be 1.JSON and so on. So far my code acts to downloading 0.JSON and 1.JSON at the same time which is not what i wanted and if i execute it again it wouldnt 2.JSON and 3.JSON. Any fixes?

```
    import urllib.request
    import os
    import json
    i=0
    url="https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"
    address="C:/Users/anton/Desktop/Python Learning/JSONS/{}.JSON".format(i)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,address)
    while address:
        i+=1
        address="C:/Users/dwika/Desktop/Python Learning/JSONS/{}.JSON".format(i)
        address=address
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,address)
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test the existence of the file (`os.path.exists`).  You could do it like this -- it will keep looping until it finds a filename that does not already exist.

```
import urllib.request
import os
import json

i = 0
url = "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"

while True:
    address = "C:/Users/dwika/Desktop/Python Learning/JSONS/{}.JSON".format(i)
    if not os.path.exists(address):
        break
    i += 1

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,address)
```

(I am guessing based on your username that `dwika` is the correct folder name, rather than `anton`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib` to get all the json files then sort them and get the number from last json filename.

```
from pathlib import Path

files = sorted(Path('C:/Users/dwika/Desktop/Python Learning/JSONS').glob('*.JSON'), key=lambda x: int(x.stem))
curr = int(files[-1].stem) + 1 if files else 0

address = "C:/Users/dwika/Desktop/Python Learning/JSONS/{}.JSON".format(curr)
```